# Selective crop in pages of a PDF document

Tags: pdf, convert

How to extract concrete sections of concrete pages in a PDF document, without converting to images first and then cropping images? Is there a way to parameterize `convert` to do this job?

Edit: Say, for example, that over a PDF file of several pages, I want to extract only an upper half in page 100, and a central square in page 200. How do I specify these coordinates and page numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use PDFCrop,

see for instructions:
http:// manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/pdfcrop.1.html

it includes these examples:

EXAMPLES

```
pdfcrop --margins 10 input.pdf output.pdf

pdfcrop --margins ’5 10 5 20’ --clip input.pdf output.pdf
```

AUTHORS

pdfcrop has been written by Heiko Oberdiek.  This manual page has  been
written  by  Frank Küster for the Debian/GNU Linux distribution and may
be freely used, modified and/or distributed by anyone.

OR

install Adobe Acrobat Pro in Wine:

https:// appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4922

you can download a version of Acrobat Pro 7 with serial number from the Adobe web site from:
https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs2-product-downloads.html#

Mind their comment though:

*Adobe has disabled the activation server for CS2 products, including     Acrobat 7, because of a technical issue. These products were released more than seven years ago and do not run on many modern operating systems; Adobe no longer supports them.
Adobe strongly advises against running unsupported and outdated software. Only customers who legitimately purchased CS2 or Acrobat 7 and need to maintain their current use of these products may use the serial numbers provided during the download.*

Comment: Is there a way to crop only on a given page? (Example added to the question.)

Comment: Simple, fist get page 100 from the pdf, then get page 200 of the pdf. Crop each as you like and merge them again. (you can automate this in a program language doing system calls)   For example, to extract pages 22-36 from a 100-page PDF file using pdftk:

  >>>$ pdftk A=100p-inputfile.pdf cat A22-36 output outfile_p22-p36.pdf 

  
>>>$ pdfunite in-1.pdf in-2.pdf in-n.pdf out.pdf
   I usualy work in Acrobat Pro (with a licence) which has a nice interface and you can delete all pages except 100 and 200 and do a manual crop on each.

Comment: Solved. But can't understand the units of `pdfcrop`, what's the meaning of bp?

Comment: FROM LaTeX but so go here too -->> The one for PostScript is bp, also called big point (1in=72bp)  SEE http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22705/what-is-the-smallest-paper-dimension-that-can-be-used-in-latex

Comment: PostScript units (there are precisely 72 PostScript units to the inch, like TeX big points) with respect to the lower left corner of the sheet of paper. SEE  >>> http://tex.loria.fr/texlive-htmldoc/dvips/dvips_5.html